# How to select a series of variables efficiently in R?

Tags: r

I have a series of variables with the variable names "HPV_x_ALL". The only difference between these names is the x, which is number (e.g., 11, 16, 18, 33). I'd like to use -rowSums- to summarize the values of HPV_x_ALL for each observation, and I tried using * to represent the numbers, but it doesn't work.
Thank you!

Update:
Hi, I added a reproducible dataset.

```
structure(list(HPV_16_ALL = c(1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HPV_18_ALL = c(0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HPV_33_ALL = c(0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = 40:45, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to be sure that this answer will be appropriate.

However, starting from this dummy example:

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Var = c(paste0("HPV_",11:15,"_ALL"),paste0("BPV_",11:15,"_ALL")),
                 Val = sample(1:100,10))

          Var Val
1  HPV_11_ALL  31
2  HPV_12_ALL  79
3  HPV_13_ALL  51
4  HPV_14_ALL  14
5  HPV_15_ALL  67
6  BPV_11_ALL  42
7  BPV_12_ALL  50
8  BPV_13_ALL  43
9  BPV_14_ALL  97
10 BPV_15_ALL  25
```

You can get the rows corresponding to "HPV_xx_ALL" by doing:

```r
grep("HPV_\\d{2}_ALL",df$Var, perl = TRUE)

[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

So, you can get the sum of rows corresponding to the pattern you are looking for by doing:

```r
sum(df[grep("HPV_\\d{2}_ALL",df$Var, perl = TRUE),"Val"])

[1] 242
```

If your pattern `HPV_xx_ALL` are columns names, you can do the same by doing:

```r
rowSums(df[,grep("HPV_\\d{2}_ALL", names(df), perl = TRUE)]
```

Does it answer your question ? If not, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset (see: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: Thank you! They are my column names. I upload a small dataset, but this solution is working!

Comment: You're welcome. Based on your dataset, you need to use the last part of my answer: `rowSums(df[,grep("HPV_\\d{2}_ALL", names(df), perl = TRUE)]`. You should get: `
 1  0  0  0  0  0`.

Comment: @user12721567. If the solution works for you, it is customary and a good practice to accept it as the answer.